# xamarin crossplatform View Binding with SubList

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xaml-binding

I am having a model like this

```
public class ExamMaster
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string StartDate {get;set;}
    public string EndDate {get;set;}
    public List<SubjectMaster> ExamSubjects {get;set;}
}


public class SubjectMaster
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int MaxMark {get;set;}
    public int MinMark {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
}
```

How to bind the ExamMaster on a xaml view . I managed to bind simple properties like this

```
    <Grid>
      <BoxView Color="#006793" />
      <ContentView Padding="20">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding StartDate}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
        But how to bind the ExamSubjects property which itself is a List??

      </ContentView>
    </Grid>
```

But how to bind the ExamSubjects property which itself is a List??

Answer (score 0):

Do this set the `ItemsSource="{Binding ExamSubjects }"` and then define your DataTemplate in order to render the properties of your List

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ExamSubjects }">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid>          
          <Label Text="{Binding Name }" FontAttributes="Bold" />
          <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MaxMark }" />
          <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MinMark }" />
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

for more details follow [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/creating/)